# Why does glewInit() result in GL_INVALID_ENUM after making some calls to glfwWindowHint()

Tags: opengl, glew, glfw

For some reason when I call glfwWindowHint():

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
```

and later make a call to:

```
glewInit()
```

I end up getting a glError: GL_INVALID_ENUM. When I leave out all of the glfwWindowHint() calls everything works fine and no glError is set. Am I using these libraries incorrectly, or if this is a bug in glfw, or glew?

Note that I'm using glew-1.10.0 and glfw-3.0.3

Here's a simple program to illustrate the issue I'm seeing:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"

int main(char* argc, char* argv[])
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; tried commenting this out but I still get the error
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        return -1;
    } 
    switch(glGetError())
    {
    case GL_INVALID_ENUM:
        std::cout << "why is this happening?";
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Why write this as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @datenwolf: Because it is asked so frequently, but since I do not see anything relevant in the "Related" sidebar I think you have a good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in a core profile context, it is invalid to query the extension string using `glGetString (...)`. You have to use `glGetStringi (...)` and query each extension one-by-one. Frankly this is terrible design, since `glGetStringi` has to be loaded through the extension loading mechanism on most platforms. It is a chicken and egg sort of situation, the proper behavior in a core profile is definitely to use `glewExperimental = TRUE` before initialization and ignore an invalid enum error immediately following `glewInit (...)`.

I should point out that this is nothing that ***you*** are doing wrong. It is a problem with how GLEW is implemented behind the scenes and a somewhat questionable decision by the OpenGL ARB. I would have left `GL_EXTENSIONS` a valid thing to query with `glGetString (...)` but defined some special string (e.g. "GL_CORE_PROFILE") to return in a core profile. Everybody wins then, the way I see it.

Incidentally, it is not the`glfwWindowHint` for major.minor 3.3 that causes this issue to show up. It is actually your use of `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE`. Core profiles are only valid for OpenGL 3.2+, so this issue will only manifest itself with a combination of major.minor ≥ 3.2 ***and*** core.

Comment: If it's a problem that glew can't avoid, shouldn't they at least swallow the error before passing it along to library users, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Lockyer: Well, since user libraries cannot restore the error state after querying it this would be a bad thing to do. What if GLEW issued `glGetError (...)` and this masked an error that was actually caused by something else? It would be great if there were a way to *peek* at the error state without removing the error from the GL, but this does not exist :-\ You can work around this yourself by clearing the error state before initializing GLEW and then querying it again after; if you get a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error, then you can ignore it.

Comment: Right, I hadn't thought of that. They have to avoid taking errors off the stack which users may have legitimately triggered, before making a call to GLEW.